# BindingSource MoveFirst/MoveLast doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

My winforms skills are a bit rusty. I'm using a `BindingSource` for a `DataGridView`. On `KeyDown` of the `DataGridView` i want to select the next/previous record which works as desired.

I want to select the first if the user hits `Keys.Down` when the last item is selected and select the last if he hits `Keys.Up` when the first item is selected. But  nothing happens then.

Here's the code:

```
private void  Grid_Keydown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        previousItem();
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        nextItem();
}

private void previousItem()
{
    BindingSource bs = null;
    switch (this.Type) // a custom enum
    {
        case AdminType.Channel:  
            bs = channelBindingSource;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (bs.Position - 1 < 0)
        bs.MoveLast();
    else
        bs.MovePrevious();
}

private void nextItem()
{
    BindingSource bs = null;
    switch (this.Type)
    {
        case AdminType.Channel:
            bs = channelBindingSource;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (bs.Position + 1 >= bs.Count)
        bs.MoveFirst();
    else
        bs.MoveNext();
}
```

Note that `bs.MoveFirst()`/`bs.MoveLast()` are called correctly but nothing happens.

**Edit**: Interesting, it works as expected when i trigger this from a button(previous/next) instead of the `DataGridView`'s `OnKeyDown`, any ideas?

Comment: could you try bs.EndEdit(); after the moveFirst/Last?

Comment: @NDJ: Thanks, but doesn't work either.

Comment: maybe something in the grid overrides the bs position. try using a "later" event like `KeyUp`

Comment: @JensKloster: Hmm, now the current item "jumps" two positions if i hit `Keys.Up/Down`. What can cause it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter perhaps the grid is set to do a "row select" instead of a "cell select". if that is the case - the the default behavior then using e.g. `Keys.Up` is to focus the previos row - therby automaticly updating the `bs.Position`.

Comment: try comment out all the shown code, and see if it works. :)

Comment: @JensKloster: Omg , it's already builtin, thanks. So i just have to implement the code for the `MoveFirst` and `MoveLast`. But the next problem is that i cannot detect when the last item is selected since `BindingSource.Position` is set before the KeyUp event is triggered. You may want to answer it anyway so i can upvote/accept it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter What needs to happen if the last (or first) item is selected? you could use `bs.PositionChanged` event instead of the grid.

Comment: @JensKloster: If the first item is selected and `Keys.Up` is pressed, the last item should be selected and if the last item was selected and the user hits `Keys.Down` then first should be selected. How would `PositionChanged` help to identify if the user wants the next or previous item? It would be triggered only if the position was already changed and not on the first or last position(which is the only relevant event).

Comment: @JensKloster: I have solved it with your suggested approach using `PositionChanged`, so you  might want to post an answer with your comments. I can add my code afterwards. Maybe there's something easier but it works.

Comment: @TimSchmelter hmm after some tests - i see what you mean. I beliver there might be a smarter way but I can't see it right now.. maybe later i well. I don't feel like posting an answer, becuase i don't feel i have a solution. But thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid automatically moves the underderlying bindingsource's position, when you move up and down.

If you want the selection to go from top to button and vice versa - you could handle the `grid_KeyDown` event an check it's position. unfortunately if you try moving the posistion, it get overridden by the gridview's `Row_Enter` Event. thus changing the bindingsource position.

In the `Grid_Keyup` event the position is already set, so you dont know if the user just move to the row, or if he/she want to move away from the row. *But* setting the `bindingSource.Position` in here actually work - and does not get overridden by the grid.

You could also use the `DataGridViewRow.Selected = true` but his does not move the underlying bindingsource's position. Also it is not ideal for grids the multiselect is enabled.

The ugly truth is that you *must* use a boolean (just like you do in you own answer), to control if the row should jump or not. :(

however you dont need to control it from the `PositionChanged` event, you can do it by just handeling the `grid_Keydown` event:

```
 private bool _changePost;
    private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var view = sender as DataGridView;
        var bs = bindingSource1;

        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up)
        {
            if (bs.Position == 0 && _changePost)
            {
                _changePost = false;
                bs.MoveLast();
            }
            if (bs.Position == 0 && !_changePost)
                _changePost = true;

        }
        else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Down)
        {
            if (bs.Position == bs.Count - 1 && _changePost)
            {
                bs.MoveFirst();
                _changePost = false;
            }
            if (bs.Position == bs.Count - 1 && !_changePost)
                _changePost = true;
        }
    }
```

This was the as clean as I could get it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's too bad that there's no approach without this ugly variable :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Jens Kloster, i have found this workaround. As he mentioned the `DataGridView` already supports moving of the position of it's `BindingSource`. So if it has focus and you hit up/down-arrow, the `BindingSource`'s `MoveNext`/`MovePrevious` are called implicitely.

I've noticed that the selected item "jumped" two positions when i handled the `KeyUp` event(which is later then the `KeyDown` event) instead, one for the programmatical and one for the builtin move.

So i only need to find a way to move the position from the first to the last and vice-versa if the up/down-keys were pressed. Therefore i have handled the `BindingSource.PositionChanged` event to set a bool variable which i can check later:

```
bool positionChanged = false;
private void Source_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    positionChanged = true;
}

private void Grid_KeyUp(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        previousItem();
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        nextItem();

    positionChanged = false;
}

private void previousItem()
{
    BindingSource bs = null;
    switch (this.Type)
    {
        case AdminType.Channel:
            bs = channelBindingSource;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (!positionChanged && bs.Position == 0)
        bs.MoveLast();
    else if (!positionChanged)
        bs.MovePrevious();
}

private void nextItem()
{
    BindingSource bs = null;
    switch (this.Type)
    {
        case AdminType.Channel:
            bs = channelBindingSource;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (!positionChanged && bs.Position == bs.Count - 1)
        bs.MoveFirst();
    else if (!positionChanged)
        bs.MoveNext();
}
```

I'm still open for better solutions since this is a bit clumsy and error-prone.